# inserting wp_nav_menu_items (or similar solution) without saving to database

Tags: wordpress

So I coded some custom menu items as drop downs that are dynamically generated. It worked fine, but then I realised they were also saved to the database. i want to create drop downs that hook in to the main menu but do NOT save in the database as they are different for every user depending on user meta, any ideas?

Also this is a child theme so has to hook into the main menu, no option of generating a new menu etc as its part of a horrible theme builder.

```
function _custom_nav_menu_item( $title, $url, $order, $parent = 0 ){
    $item = new stdClass();
    $item->ID = 1000000 + $order + parent;
    $item->db_id = $item->ID;
    $item->title = $title;
    $item->url = $url;
    $item->menu_order = $order;
    $item->menu_item_parent = $parent;
    $item->type = '';
    $item->object = '';
    $item->object_id = '';
    $item->classes = array();
    $item->target = '';
    $item->attr_title = '';
    $item->description = '';
    $item->xfn = '';
    $item->status = '';
    return $item;
}

// Custom nav menu. Adding dropdowns etc according to user permissions.
function custom_nav_menu_items( $items, $menu ){

    $user_permissions = user_is_loggedin_with_permissions();

    if( $menu->slug == 'main-menu-english' ){

        // Announcements dropdown, users allowed regions.
        $top = _custom_nav_menu_item( 'Announcements', site_url( '/announcements' ), 2 );
        $items[] = $top;
        $i = 1;

        foreach( $user_permissions['Region'] as $region ){

            $for_humans = ucfirst( str_replace( '_', ' ', $region ) );
            $items[] = _custom_nav_menu_item( $for_humans, site_url( '?post_type=announcements&regions='.$region ), '10'.$i, $top->ID );
            $i++;
        }
    }

    return $items;
}
add_filter( 'wp_get_nav_menu_items', 'custom_nav_menu_items', 20, 2 );
```

Comment: Can you post some code? How did they end up in the database if you've injected them into the output via a filter?

Comment: Hi, yes of-course. Code added. Dont know how they are saving but when I check the menu in the backend the new items are in there.

Comment: I'm unsure if this will trigger when saving a menu, but it might. If it does, not modifying $items if `is_admin()` is true should be enough, I believe.

Comment: Thank you, thank you, thank you :) I have been over complicating things and over looking the simple things. It has been a long time, big job and lack of sleep :) How do I merit you for this?

Comment: You're welcome! It often helps to have somebody look at it who isn't in too deep, I've often experienced that myself.